# How to design a SQL subquery?

Tags: mysql

The problem in question states:

> Return all accessible information about paintings of a painter that are more expensive than the average price of all paintings of the respective painter. Use a correlated query in the WHERE clause. For simplicity, also use a convenient view, instead of a join in the outer query.

[Here is a link to the Schema](https://github.com/sgtjond/CS345/blob/master/paintings.sql)

Here is the view I've been provided with:

[image]

And here is the partial solution I currently have:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    art
WHERE
    price > (SELECT AVG(price) AS 'avg_price'
        FROM
            art
        WHERE

        GROUP BY
            painter_id);
```

So, I know have a query whose return is based on a single piece of information returned from the subquery, but the subquery returns a table of information (in this case, the average price of all the paintings created by a specific painter, grouped by painter_id). I know I need to pull out one entry from this table based on the painter_id from the painting in question. My problem is, I have no idea how to go about making that comparison. Am I implementing the subquery correctly? If not, what do I need to change to get back on track; and if so, what am I missing? Will I need a second subquery to do this, or can I do it with just one?

I am new to SQL, and just learned about subqueries earlier this week. I do know the basics of regular queries, but I currently have a tenuous idea of how queries and subqueries work with each other.

### Edit

This is what the solution should look like in the Result Grid:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is very close, you just need to connect (correlate) the subquery to the main query, using the value of `painter_id`:

```
SELECT *
FROM art a1
WHERE price > (SELECT AVG(price)
               FROM art a2
               WHERE a2.painter_id = a1.painter_id);
```

Note that since you are qualifying the subquery with the `painter_id` you no longer need the `GROUP BY` clause. Also you don't need an alias for the average price as you don't ever access that column directly.

Another way to do the same thing is with a `JOIN` to a table of average price values:

```
SELECT *
FROM art a1
JOIN (SELECT painter_id, AVG(price) AS avg_price
      FROM art
      GROUP BY painter_id) a2
ON a2.painter_id = a1.painter_id AND a1.price > a2.avg_price
```

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you so much, I didn't realize instantiating a table multiple times (for lack of a better term) like that would have that effect!